# The method getBytes() in the type "x" is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java

In a program in Java I am trying to use the stream bytes and the pipelines for sharing informations among threads. However whenever I trying to use getBytes() I get the following error:
*The method getBytes() in the type "Consumi " is not applicable for the arguments (String)*

The "SimulaConsumi" file where I am trying to use it (disclaimer: not finished) :

```
package tryout5_stream_bytes;

import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class SimulaConsumi implements Runnable {
    private AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private PipedOutputStream pos = null;

    public SimulaConsumi(PipedOutputStream pos){
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        isRunning.set(true);

        while(isRunning.get()){
            Consumi c = new Consumi((float) (30 * Math.random()));

            byte[] message = null;

            try{
                message = c.getBytes("UTF-16");
            } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

and the file Consumi:

```
package tryout5_stream_bytes;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Consumi implements Serializable{

    private float consumi = 0.0F;

    public Consumi(float consumi){
        this.consumi = consumi;
    }

    public float getConsumi(){
        return consumi;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes(){
        return String.valueOf(consumi).getBytes();
    }
}
```

I currently have no clue on how I can fix this.

Comment: `Consumi::getBytes` does not expect a parameter. Don't pass a parameter.

Comment: Look at `public byte[] getBytes()` - see no args

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am sorry I don't understand

Comment: Change in Consumi class: public byte[] getBytes(String encode){...

Comment: @LucaGirotti here `message = c.getBytes("UTF-16");` you're passing a parameter to `getBytes`, but if you read the definition of `getBytes` inside of `Consumi` you'll notice it doesn't expect a parameter.

Comment: @pringi Ok ok, that seems to work, however the "catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
} "

is giving me " Unable to catch block for UnsuporttedEncodingException. This exception is never thrown in the body statement"

Comment: @LucaGirotti because the method getBytes() doesn't throw any exception. You can remove the try/catch block entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your call `getBytes("UTF-16")` suggests that you want the content in a specific character encoding, but the class `Consumi` only offers a parameterless method `getBytes()` which uses the platform’s default encoding. Since it’s rather unlikely that your platform’s default encoding is UTF-16 and you don’t want to rely on likelihoods anyway, change `Consumi`’s method

```java
public byte[] getBytes(){
    return String.valueOf(consumi).getBytes();
}
```

to

```java
public byte[] getBytes(String charsetName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return String.valueOf(consumi).getBytes(charsetName);
}
```

In principle, you could keep both methods, but using the platform’s default encoding can easily lead to errors. Mind that this applies to the other end too, when converting the bytes back into a `String`.